# What algorithm is used for std::rotate in this example?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to find out the name for an algorithm which is basically the one used on cppreference for std::rotate. This is the code:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt rotate(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt n_first, ForwardIt last)
{
   if(first == n_first) return last;
   if(n_first == last) return first;
 
   ForwardIt read      = n_first;
   ForwardIt write     = first;
   ForwardIt next_read = first; // read position for when "read" hits "last"
 
   while(read != last) {
      if(write == next_read) next_read = read; // track where "first" went
      std::iter_swap(write++, read++);
   }
 
   // rotate the remaining sequence into place
   (rotate)(write, next_read, last);
   return write;
}
```

(Reference at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

I thought it was the Juggling algorithm, but I don't see anything related to the greatest common divisor, so I suppose it's not that?

Comment: this is just the most straightforward way to rotate elements. Does it need a name? Note that cppref also links to  libstdc++ and libc++ implementation, while the "possible implementation" is just for illustration

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of it, so I thought I'd look for the algorithm. Is this O(1) space complexity, by the way?

Comment: there is no extra memory used, its all about swapping elements.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep 1 pointer does not change complexity of memory usage

Comment: Well, thanks. Guess I'll go learn the Juggling Algorithm in that case, which seems to be used by one implementation.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I didn't claim it would not be O(1)

Comment: Actually this code might be `O(d)` space complexity, where `d` is distance between `first` and `last`, because of the recursion. However, the algorithm itself should be `O(1)` space complexity, and is possible to be implemented with `O(1)` space complexity.

Comment: The greatest common divisor is hidden in the recursion. In every recursive call, distances `last - first` and `last - n_first` follow the iterations of the Euclidean algorithm. At the bottom, when `first == n_first` or `n_first == last` and the recursion stops, `last - first` is the GCD.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik wow, I didn't see that. That's quite smart! Thanks for letting me know